# Entity Framework Object being added but never commited to database

Tags: entity-framework

I've been asked to fix a problem with a WCF service that uses the entity framework for it's data access. Adds of a whole object work great, but updates fail because one object isn't being detected.

Object model is like so
Parent -> Collection Of Children -> Collection of Children -> **Child Object**

The Child object is the one that isn't being saved. I see that it is in the added state in the ObjectStateManager, but because it's parent didn't change, the change doesn't seem to go to the database. If I add a new object to the Child Object's collection and a Child Object it picks up the change and saves it to the database, but if the parent collection doesn't change, it won't ever submit the changes to the database.

What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe you could try adding `context.ChildObjectSet.Add(ChildObject)`; I remember I had similar problem in EF 1, but it was a long time ago.

Comment: @Josh: How Id's are assigned (sql server generated, code assigned), are you using POCO objects? What version of EF you are using?

Comment: I am doing an add to the navigation property and adding the object to the context.
@Broken Pipe, I'm using EF 4, IDs are GUID, so code assigned and the objects are .TT generated with partial classes to expand on them some more.

Comment: @Josh: Check generated code for Entities, maybe there are relationship state management problems like having Child in Parent.Childs collection and not set Child.Parent reference, for two sided relationships.

Comment: @Broken Pipe, I'm checking the relationship, and I did a GetAllRelatedEnds and see both parents. Now I also see that the object has it's "IsRelationship" set to false" and _owner is null. Have no clue where to see or set Child.Parent reference.

Comment: Josh: If entities where generated using standard POCO TT, there should be no problem there. However if not there could be a mistake, anyway before messing with it try specifying parent explicitly, in the code where you do: Parent.Children[*].Children[*].Add(Child), after this try Child.Parent = Parent.Childern[*]

Comment: @Broken Pipe, I think I found the problem. The entities were created using the standard POCO TT. The issue with this is that this object is added to the disconnected entity and does not contain a piece of it's foreign key. So on an Add, the foreign key gets populated, but on an update, the foreign key is blank and EF eats the object, I think. To prevent any sort of foreign key violation. Since this is coming from a web service I have seem to hit the edge case and now must refactor the update process since I also saw it duplicates the object. It didn't help during debugging EF gave me no info!